# libpng warning: Ignoring bad adaptive filter type

Tags: warnings, kill, libpng

my app was killed,and the log :libpng warning: Ignoring bad adaptive filter type.
I want to know the reason,and the solution.

Answer (score 6):

The question gives insufficient information to provide a complete answer.

The "bad adaptive filter type" message means that the PNG file is either corrupted or was generated by a buggy encoder.

Each scanline of a PNG file begins with a "filter type" byte which must be 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before, the image was corrupted by unknown reason, the solution of catching such an error can be using the code below (in Python):

```
try:
    Image.open(path).tobytes()
except IOError:
    print('detect error img %s' % path)
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not figure out why this happened. But I found a solution for this situation.

Just use Python to re-save the file, after re-save, everything looks ok.

Here's my solution.

First install **Pillow**.

```bash
pip3 install Pillow
```

Then use Pillow:

```py
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('input/img.png')
im.save('output/img.png')
```